# Simple HTML DOM works for one URL but not others

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

My code is below:

It only works if I navigate one web page.

```
<?php
   include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
   echo '<table border=1px>';
    for ($x = 1; $x <= 2; $x++) {
        $target_url = 'http://www.example.com/movie.php?movieid='.$x;
        $html = new simple_html_dom();
        $html->load_file($target_url);
        echo '<tr>';
            foreach($html->find('div.movieboxsright') as $div){
                foreach($div->find('div[class=bl_tle_mvi blue_tlte]') as $title){
                    echo '<td>'.$title->find('a')[0]->innertext.'</td>';
                }
                foreach($div->find('div[class=movieboxssec]') as $details){
                    echo '<td>'.$details->find('span[style=border:1px solid #c61a17; margin:0px 4px;]',0)->innertext.'</td>';

                }
            }

        echo '</tr>';
    }
echo '</table>';
?>
```

The error I am getting is: Call to a member function find() on null in /Library/WebServer/Documents/simple_html_dom.php on line 1113

I tried to check where the error is and it comes at the last line where I am trying to find span element with a particular style. I have checked the website I am trying to access and this tag is there on both the pages.

Comment: Try str_get_html, and consider using curl

Comment: You should use `file_get_html` or `str_get_html` or use curl to make faster process. Also, Can You show use on which url, you get this error. Maybe, it blocks you due to a bot sequence.